# HTML Onlcick event only works with # Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I attempt to call a function my this page using the below code. I just seems to refresh the page and not call the script.

```
    <form role="search" name="locationForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="locationInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="start();">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

If I add a '#' to the end of the url, reload the page, then the onlcick event works as it is suppose to.

As far as I knew these were Anchor tags and I have no idea why they would be required in the calling of a function.

How do I correct this? As I don't want to have to use the #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `button` element, whose default behavior, when clicked, submits its parent form. `return false` will stop the form from submitting:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" onclick="start(); return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for that. Thinking about it now, it makes sense that is is trying to POST rather than just action onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the button to automatically submit, you could change its `type` to `button`. Then, all it will do is run its onclick code. (You can still have that code submit the form manually)

Comment: Also a helpful response. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to run the start() function when you submit the form?
You said you're working with an click event listener.
Try to listen for the submit event, instead.

```
$('#your_form_id').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    your script...
});
```

The code above basically does this.
Furthermore, the preventDefault keeps the form from actually submitting itself.
You could access the form data with

```
$('#your_form_id').serialize();
```

I hope this pushes you into the right direction!